# install SQL server setup has encoutered the error on Win 7 :

Tags: sql-server

I wanna install SQL Server 2012 Enterprise edition but I have an issue during the installation.

I'm working on a Win 7 OS, i5, x64, sp1.

I tried to install it on my laptop and it doesn't work. After installing rules this error comes up:

> SQL server setup has encoutered the following error: There was a
>   failure to calculate the default value of setting INSTANCEID. Error
>   code 0x85640001.

Now, I don't know what I can do? =/

Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

i know nothing about that specific error message but maybe it is related with the fact that win 7 is not a supported operating system for that sql server version.

you can check on [ms website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506%28v=sql.110%29.aspx#top_principal): the enterprise edition requires a server operating system.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Enterprise does not support Windows 7 -

[Hardware and Software Requirements for Installing SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms143506(v=sql.110).aspx)