# SQL Server 2012 installation on Windows 8.1

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2012

I am trying to install SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition, And I am getting this error:

> there was a failure to calculate the default value of setting
>   instanceid

What can be the reason of that problem ?

Comment: What type of SQL Server are you trying to install? Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26158551/install-sql-server-setup-has-encoutered-the-error-on-win-7

Comment: it is the developer edition

Comment: I think this link will help: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/38b62904-954c-4a97-a5ce-f1c706d30d36/problems-installing-sql-server-2012-developer-edition-on-win7-professional-service-pack-1-x64?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've experienced the same exact issue before. One of the things that you can do to verify if the image is correct, is to install this tool https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11533 and find the checksum where you downloaded the image. If there are any issues it will let you know and it will help narrow down whether or not the issue is with the image or something on your system. In my case, it just worked after a restart, and the image validated fine.